# Clicking a button on Google Docs through Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am trying to create a chrome extension that will click on a button on Google Docs when you click a button on the extension. Below is my attempt to this problem (this doesn't seem to work, I am just going with clicking Print button on the docs).

manifest.json

```
{  
    "manifest_version": 2,  

    "name": "Google Docs Button Click",  
    "description": "Google Docs Button Click Simulator",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*.docs.google.com/*","*://*/*"],  

    "browser_action": {  
        "default_icon": "cursor.png",  
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
    <head><title>activity</title></head>  
<body>  
    <button id="clickactivity">click</button>  
    <script src="popup.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
}

document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

content_script.js

```
function clickButton() {
    var buttons = document.getElementById("printButton");
    buttons.click();
}

clickButton();
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Currently It is not simple to interact with Google-Docs HTML Elements.

In my recent experience ( after reading your questions and playing around ), The DOM listeners for mouse click is attached to the "printButton" element.

If you use inspect element to show the JS-listeners for the "printButton" element ( with exclude-ancestor-listeners turned on ), you will see that document doesn't have any listeners for mouse-clicks.

So we would need to invoke the .click() call somewhere else.
One other way can be to grab XY page-position, and attempt to do mouse-click on the body element.
But I think Google Product Team purposedly hide this capabilities away from users to reduce malicous actions.

Summary: I think it is not possible, unless you work in Google and you know a secret way.

---

With that said, your code is trying to print the document.
So how about

```
window.print()
```

:D

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the options. Actually, I started with print button, but have other task bar functions to implement as well, ex. undo, redo, zoom, etc. So, just finding an alternative for print won't resolve the entire problem statement :(

Comment: They have API for these things, like they have for [Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets). Which chimes in with why they probably look at the `isTrusted` property of your synthetic events or otherwise ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `google-docs-utils` library.

```js
GoogleDocsUtils.pressOn.PrintDialog();
```

- GitHub - https://github.com/Amaimersion/google-docs-utils
- NPM - https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-docs-utils